# Replicator in State Machine workflow

Tags: workflow, workflow-activity, state-machine

I'm working on a custom approval workflow with a few twists.

Given the different states, and reviews, and the need to step back in some scenarios, I'm going with a state machine workflow.

In one of the steps, the number of reviewers is meant to be dynamic, and this is where I'm hitting my problem, the same described at http://www.pseale.com/blog/SharePointWorkflowNuttinessVolume1.aspx

So, I can't use a replicator to track task changes in a single state. 
The only workaround I found so far was the ugly solution of creating 20 review tasks when in parallel when entering the state, then have 20 event handlers to deal with all these tasks, plus the eventhandlers on delays and other modifications, but effectively locking the process to a max of 20 reviewers, which even if it is way above the average, it's still a very ugly and time consuming solution, that pollutes my whole workflow design.

Any suggestion on how to improve this? Any workaround? Any alternative path that doesn't involve third party products?